# CacheHelper saving the same cached files under different names

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

I'm having troubles with the CakePHP's (2.3) CacheHelper.
This is realy a powerful tool, but it's not so suitable for what I'm doing.

I have a internationalised website and the language is set either by the user's preferences or by "forcing" it with an URL argument (lang:xx).

So, the cached page "controller/action/yy" can be the same page as "controller/action/yy/lang:xx". And worst, "controller/action/yy" can be cached in english, french or whatever.

Is there a way to change the name (the prefix is clearly not a solution here) of the cached file (so that "controller/action/yy" will always be cached as "controller/action/yy/lang:xx" by adding the user's preferences language) ?

Thanks in advance !
Sébastien

Answer (score 0):

You can in your beforeRender change the prefix of the file:

```
Configure::write('Cache.viewPrefix', 'YOURPREFIX');
```

And you can get your prefix from params or session (depends of your app).
I didn't get why prefix is not useful. You will have one file for each language for each page. Something like "eng_my_action" file. 
If you want to save only 1 file and translate it with the user language makes non sense. Because view already do that (only a parser of the data).

Fonts:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html#using-the-helper (looking for new in version 2.3)

Well,
I will sample the awnser to you understand:

```
public function beforeRender(){
    $lang = isset($this->params["named"]["lang"]) ? $this->params["named"]["lang"] : "eng"; // verify if is the default language(eng) or is in params
    if($this->Auth->user("lang")){
        $lang = $this->Auth->user("lang"); // This is a example how to take the default language from a user. You need to change it to your app.
    }
    Configure::write('Cache.viewPrefix', $lang);
}
```

Comment: You misread my question, I don't ask "how to cache the same file under different names" but insted "how to NOT cache the same file under different names". So, how to cache the requested URL "controller/action/yy" under "controller/action/yy/lang:en" if the preference for language is "english". So it don't save the same file under two different files.

Comment: I added a full example to you understand how to set the default language. I didnt get why you checked "not useful". Anyway, I think this example will work to you.

Comment: No, realy, this won't work. I don't know how to explain it better...
If the named param is not set, there will be another file saved in the cache because "controller/action/yy" don't match "controller/action/yy/lang:xx". So there will be two same cache files : "controller_action_yy" and "controller_action_yy_lang_xx". The prefix is not solving anything!

Comment: Try to change your "lang:xx" params to something like this: "controller/action/yy?lang=xx"

Comment: I'm reading the source code and I think you cant do that without replace the original CacheHelper.php. You can see here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/CacheHelper.php#L281 and here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php#L588 that all params are used to generate the filename. Sorry for didnt understand the original question.